# getting error: subprocess-exited-with-error when dockerizing my project for the package reportlab, but this is not added in my requirements.txt

Tags: python, django, docker, alpine-linux, reportlab

getting the following error when dockerizing my project this is the error message

```
Collecting reportlab>=3.3.0
  Downloading reportlab-3.6.12.tar.gz (4.5 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 4.5/4.5 MB 3.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [10 lines of output]
      ##### setup-python-3.10.6-linux-x86_64: ================================================
      ##### setup-python-3.10.6-linux-x86_64: Attempting build of _rl_accel
      ##### setup-python-3.10.6-linux-x86_64: extensions from 'src/rl_addons/rl_accel'
      ##### setup-python-3.10.6-linux-x86_64: ================================================
      ##### setup-python-3.10.6-linux-x86_64: ===================================================
      ##### setup-python-3.10.6-linux-x86_64: Attempting build of _renderPM
      ##### setup-python-3.10.6-linux-x86_64: extensions from 'src/rl_addons/renderPM'
      ##### setup-python-3.10.6-linux-x86_64: ===================================================
      ##### setup-python-3.10.6-linux-x86_64: will use package libart 2.3.21
      !!!!! cannot find ft2build.h
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1
ERROR: Service 'demo_project' failed to build : Build failed
```

this is my requirements.txt file'

```
celery==5.2.7
channels==3.0.4
Django==3.2.11
django-celery-beat==2.2.1
django-celery-results==2.3.1
django-environ==0.9.0
django-filter==21.1
Pillow==9.0.1
psycopg2-binary==2.9.3
pyotp==2.6.0
razorpay==1.3.0
redis==4.4.0
xhtml2pdf==0.2.5
```

and this is my dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.10.6-alpine
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
WORKDIR /demo_project

COPY ./requirements.txt ./requirements.txt

RUN pip install --upgrade pip wheel setuptools
RUN apk add gcc python3-dev jpeg-dev zlib-dev gpgme-dev libc-dev musl-dev g++

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY ./demo_project /demo_project
```

I am new to docker please let me know whats missing or need to be changed

I tried to dockerize my project and I expected it to run correctly and get the url in the browser, but when I am running it in docker the requirements are not installing correctly.